# How to set serverside timestamp when create new record using python driver for cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-python-driver

I have `cassandra` model as below.

```
from uuid import uuid4
from uuid import uuid1

from cassandra.cqlengine import columns, connection
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model
from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table


class BaseModel(Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    created_timestamp = columns.TimeUUID(primary_key=True,
                                         clustering_order='DESC',
                                         default=uuid1)
    deleted = columns.Boolean(required=True, default=False)

class OtherModel(BaseModel):
    __table_name__ = 'other_table'
    name = columns.Text(required=True, default='')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection.setup(hosts=['localhost'],
                     default_keyspace='test')
    sync_table(OtherModel)

    OtherModel.create(id='d43ca2c3-b670-4efc-afd7-b46ada88c3fc', name='test')
```

When I create record, it set `created_timestamp` of my sytem or from where I execute this code.

My system and `cassandra` server has different timestamp.

If I execute this where system time is `2017-01-13 10:20:30` then it set timestame as same. and if I again execute same from another system, where `timestamp` is `2017-01-13 10:20:20`, then it set same.

When I run query like

```
select * from test.other_table where id=d43ca2c3-b670-4efc-afd7-b46ada88c3fc limit 1;
```

It should return me `latest`(last) record which inserted last, but as the system timestamp is different from where I inserted record, it gives first record which inserted first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema created from the above python code is:

```
CREATE TABLE test.other_table (
    id uuid,
    created_timestamp timeuuid,
    deleted boolean,
    name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, created_timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_timestamp DESC)
```

Given your example, created_timestamp is a constituent of the primary key, so there will be two distinct rows 10:20:30 and 10:20:20 in the table.  With order set to DESC, your read query will return values in sorted order, largest first, or 2017-01-13 10:20:30.  The order the rows are inserted doesn't matter because created_timestamp is a clustering column.

If created_timestamp was not part of the primary key then Cassandra would return only the latest value.  Cassandra has an internal cell timestamp generated by the coordinator which determines when a cell was inserted or updated.  It's used by Cassandra's merge process during a read request to determine the last value inserted.  You can not set this from client code, but you can view the upsert time with the CQL [writetime()](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_writetime.html) function.

For example,

```
select id, dateOf(created_timestamp), writetime(name) from other_table;
```

will return:

```
 id                                   | system.dateof(created_timestamp) | writetime(name)
--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------
 d43ca2c3-b670-4efc-afd7-b46ada88c3fc |         2017-01-14 23:09:08+0000 | 1484435348108365
 d43ca2c3-b670-4efc-afd7-b46ada88c3fc |         2017-01-14 23:07:30+0000 | 1484435250481046
```

If you wish to use the coordinator's timestamp, you will have to use a CQL statement instead of the object-mapper:

```
import uuid
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect("test")

stmt = session.prepare(
"""
    INSERT INTO test.other_table (id,created_timestamp) VALUES (?,now());
"""
)
session.execute(stmt,[uuid.uuid4()])
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but I cant chage my model, I have to use same model with `created_timestamp` as `clustering_order=DESC`

Comment: If you have option, to set server time when record created, that will really help me.

Comment: You can do this with CQL from python, but not using the object mapper.

Comment: means, from python, we cant use `cassandra` function to add data?

Comment: you can use 'now' from CQL in python, see my edit above.